# Building a site with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone direct me to maybe some documentation or tutorials on how to build a site with node.js. Currrently, I am using mostly jQuery, PHP, mysqli prepared statements, and a few other things for building sites, but I am interested in node.js, but I don't really know much about it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The DailyJS blog is currently running a series called "Let's make a web app", where they are building a notepad web app using NodeJS, week by week. They are currently up to the sixth post, but there's plenty there to get you started already, with introductions to setting up the environment, connecting to a DB, using templates, and the Express/Connect middleware stack.

http://dailyjs.com/tags.html#lmawa

The blog also has "node roundups" where they highlight various node modules from time to time.

As for documentation, there's obviously the [NodeJS documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.2.5/api.html) , but [Express' documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) is likely more helpful to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

http://screenr.com/mAL is the intro screencast to Express JS - watch it full screen to read what's being typed. More of these are linked from the Express github page https://github.com/visionmedia/express

http://howtonode.org/ is a good blog, though some of the articles might be a little out of date because it started when node was so new.

http://thechangelog.com/tagged/node.js features good links to node libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Give [DocPad](http://docpad.org) a whirl: http://docpad.org

> [DocPad](http://docpad.org) is a CMS with a document-management based approach. It's actively maintained and supported by a growing community. It's modular, easy to extend and able to be used inside bigger systems. It already supports lots of markups and pre-processors through [plugins](http://docpad.org/docs/plugins) and [powers many websites](http://docpad.org/docs/showcase).